# node.js respond after success insert in mongo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm doing an ajax $.post to a node.js route which inserts into a mongodb collection

```
collection.insert(req.body.content, function () {
    return req.body.content
});
```

How do I return something so that I can do something with the response in the client callback?

For example in php I can echo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should have access to the request object (req in your example) and a response object.  All you need to do is write to the response object.

```
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-type': 'text/plain' // or whatever content type you want
});
// you can use res.write also, but call end when you are done.
res.end('the text you want to send');
```